# Metaball Instances not displaying in Render using Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a bunch of moving points that I have scaled and and instanced in geometry nodes.

It shows in the viewport but as the title suggests, not in the render.

[image]

[image]

Metaballs don't love geometry nodes so I had to do an instancing on the vertices in order for them to show up in viewport. Anyway to get metaballs to render in geometry nodes?

[image]

Comment: In EEVEE you can render them using View -> Viewport render animation

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, so to solve it you need to export an image sequence, this way blender updates the metaballs and shows them.

If you animated the metaballs don't worry if they don't show up in a single image render, render the whole animation and they will be there.

One thing: in the first frame the metaballs don't show up, so you need to render out an additional frame before the first frame, so change the start frame from 1 to 0, and then delete the exported 0th frame bc that's blank.

If you want to make a still image, render out two frames as an animation and save the one that has the metaballs in it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).